# embedding a html resume (with its CSS style sheet) to another html page

Tags: css, html

What's the easiest way to integrate one html page into another? I am working on my personal website, and I have a template that I'm editing. Now I found a free resume html code that I can use, but when I try to add it to my website everything is messed up! The two CSS style files are not compatible with one another, and I honestly have no clue on what to do. I tried copying some of the styling from one CSS file to the other, but the result is just not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try nesting the HTML resume on it's own page and just embed it on whatever page you wish using an iframe element.

Comment: Could you please develop? I'm new to this, so I'm not sure what you're talking about

Comment: Never thought it may be that easy!